# self.view insertSubView .... not supposed to be self.view, but what?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController which shows different UIViewController sub-classes. In the main UIViewController.m, I have a sub-class called 'Home' load on app start.

Now, which the Home view loaded, I have a button which I want to use to switch to another view called 'PreGameInfo'. I'm trying to use the code below:

```
- (IBAction)showPreGameInfo:(id)sender {
    [self.view insertSubview:preGameInfo.view atIndex:0];
}
```

It doesn't work, and I know it's because the 'self.view' needs to refer to the main UIViewController rather than the self of the 'Home' view. Does anyone know how to insertSubView to the main UIViewController when using a UIButton whilst in a SubView???

Thank you!

Comment: This is very confusing... If you follow the naming scheme things will be a lot better! Is your root view controller a class called `MainViewController`? Is `Home` a UIView or a UIViewController (you should name it `HomeView` or HomeViewController` respectively). Likewise, it's better to name PreGameInfo `PreGameInfoViewController`.

Comment: Now back to your question. I assume you're not using UINavigationController. Did you init your `PreGameInfoViewController` before you try to add its view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a delagate. It very easy

So implement this in your information view controller;

In the InformationViewController.h

```
@protocol InformationViewControllerDelegate;

@interface InformationViewController : UIViewController {
    id <InformationViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <InformationViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (IBAction)returnBack:(id)sender;

@end

@protocol InformationViewControllerDelegate

- (void)InformationViewControllerDidFinish:(InformationViewController *)controller;

@end
```

in the InformationViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)returnBack:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate InformationViewControllerDidFinish:self];
}
```

And use the delegate in any view controller you need it like this :

In the HomeViewController.h

```
#import "InformationViewController.h"
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController <InformationViewControllerDelegate> {

}
```

Write the method to change the view from Home view to Information view

```
- (IBAction)goToInformationView:(id)sender;
```

In the HomeViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)goToInformationView:(id)sender {
    InformationViewController *controller = [[InformationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;
// You can chose the transition you want here (they are 4 see UIModalTransitionStyle)
        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller release];
    }
```

And the last but not least the delegate method it inform the HomeViewController when the InformationViewController had finished

```
- (void)InformationViewControllerDidFinish:(InformationViewController *)controller {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)showPreGameInfo:(id)sender {
    [superview insertSubview:preGameInfo.view atIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this code work?

```
[self.parentViewController.view addSubview:myView];
```

Comment: It depends a lot to the context you are

Comment: @buzzkip How many viewControllers have you got? Because you can access self.parentViewController.parentViewController.view

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in the modalView:

```
[self presentModalViewController:preGameInfo animated:YES]
```

or you can do something like this...

This line will add your new view to windows rootViewControllers view

```
[self.view.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:preGameInfo.view];
```